# Changes made in my source code is not getting reflected in my outlook add-in

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, microsoft-edge, outlook-web-addins, edge-devtools

I am storing a user input(which is a url) using roaming settings and appending that with rest of the url

```
//source code snippet
 function UserAction() {
            var username = $('#username').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
            var apiurl = Office.context.roamingSettings.get("userInput") + "TokenResource.svc/";
```

But when I run the solution and debug it, I can see that the text that I'm appending is different(old text instead of the current text in source code)

[code snippet when checked while debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZAnA.png)

I have tried clean solution and ctrl+F5, which worked when I faced similar problem earlier, but it is of no use this time.

Update: It works when I shut down my system and start it again. It does not work even when I restart it, Only shutting down the system makes it work properly. This is annoying because whenever I make any change I would have to shut down my system and start it again in order for the changes to reflect in my add-in.

Answer (score 0):

Check the design of the app - Outlook does tend to cache files, so you may need to include a cache-clearing mechanism, such as having your target HTML page (which the manifest points to) include a script that has a different name, or deploy a new manifest each time to a different target HTML page.  Less painful than shutting down your system.